# does jqgrid work with jquery-1.5?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i can't seem to find a clear  answer as on the jqgrid blog it talks about currently writing tests against 1.5.x.   Does that mean the latest jqgrid does work with 1.5 or not.  I am of course testing it and things seems to work but i just want to be careful and make sure i am not missing something.

if there answer is no, is there any visibility around a new jqgrid version for 1.5 support?

Comment: In all demos which I wrote last time I used jQuery 1.5.1. I don't has any problem. So it seems to me save to use 1.5.1/1.5.2. If you will find a strange situation where you suspect that the reason is jQuery bug you can just post new question. The main problem to answer on you question is: jqGrid has now no unit tests which can be used to verify the compatibility of jqGrid with jQuery. So the only way is to try this and ask expirience of other people (what you do with the questin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume no. Unless they have a beta build available, I think this means they are currently testing the jQuery 1.5.1-compatible version of jqGrid. I would keep checking for updates on their blog, and post on their [forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393).

If you must use jqGrid,  I would suggest you use a version of jQuery jqGrid is compatible with, or, if you must use 1.5.1 for some reason, there is always noConflict, but...that's iffy, not recommended, and I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: thanks.  My issue is that the solution to another bug that i have is to upgrade to jquery 1.5 so i am stuck :(.  Most of my jqgrids seem to work but for one of them, no data is showing up on the grid even though i see data coming back from the grid.  what is "noConflict" ??

Comment: It is to make sure that the jQuery library does not conflict with another - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/